# How to update column records in database?

Tags: sql, database, sql-update

I'm trying to update the records in a column within database. My current codes are as below:

```
curs = conn.cursor()
statement='SELECT column FROM table'
curs.execute(statement)
curs.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES (4, 'Five')")
```

In my understanding, the 4th row of the column should be updated to 'Five'. After I ran it, there is no error, but no update neither. There must be something wrong in my codes, or I'm missing something important. 
What if I want to update the whole column's records? Thanks in advance for any clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem using the codes below:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
curs = conn.cursor()
statement='UPDATE table SET column = false'
curs.execute(statement)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Tks for you all's help

Answer (score 3):

```
update `table_name` set `column_name` ='value'
```

although you want to make VERY certain you are trying to update ALL of the rows to that new column values, otherwise you need to add

```
where `unique_key` ='unique_value'
```

Comment: I tried your codes but it's giving me an error of 'invalid syntax'

Comment: @widget: That syntax (because of the dreaded backticks) will only work with MySQL. Simply remove them and you have a standard compliant statement that will run with any DBMS

Answer (score 2):

An `insert` does not update values in a database, it adds records.  You need to use an `UPDATE` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the version of SQL you're using MSSQL, Oracle, MySQL you'll need different syntax.  Looks like you're using MSSQL so you'll want to start with this:

```
UPDATE table SET column = "Five"
```

But you can't just say set row 4 to X value, SQL doesn't keep a set row number like an Excel spreadsheet.  You'll want to add an int column and call it something like PK_tablename and set it to be the primary key for that table.  Then you can write a statement like this and it will always update the correct row:

```
UPDATE table SET column = "Five" WHERE PK_tablename = 4
```

I would suggest reading up on Primary Keys in your SQL help.

Answer (score 1):

You're using an `INSERT` statement, not an `UPDATE` statement.  As others have stated, this will insert a record rather than update one.

There are essentially 4 basic operations for simple SQL queries:

- SELECT: Use this to view data.  `JOIN` tables, set a `WHERE` clause, etc. to manipulate the view of the data.  This is the safest operation (though a bad `SELECT` can bring a server's performance to its knees).
- INSERT: This will insert a row into the table.  It's fairly safe, as it doesn't change any existing data.
- UPDATE: This will update one *or* _more_ rows in the table.  The main thing to worry about here is the `WHERE` clause.  If you don't include one, you will update *every* row in the table.  Generally you want to test your `WHERE` clause in a `SELECT` statement first to make absolutely sure you're updating *only* the rows you want to update.
- DELETE: This is, naturally, the most dangerous.  Again, without a `WHERE` clause it will delete *all* rows in the table.  Test your `WHERE` clause to make sure you're deleting *only* the rows you want to delete.

From the looks of your `INSERT` statement, it seems that you're trying to update a row based on a key (the number 4).  Based on the lack of error, it doesn't seem to actually be a key.  If it was the table's key, it would have returned an error saying that you can't insert a row with a duplicate key.

It *seems* (based on the limited information in the question, naturally) that what you want is something along the lines of:

```
UPDATE table SET column = 'five' WHERE id = 4
```

More information can be found [here](http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-update-sql-tutorial/), among many other places.

Comment: I tried the part:UPDATE table SET column = 'five'    but it keeps giving me an error of 'invalid syntax' pointing to the table word. do i need to quote it or..?

Comment: @widget: What are the actual names of the table and the column?  If the table is indeed called "table" then try identifying it as: `UPDATE [table] SET [column] ...` instead.  If the name of something conflicts with a reserved word, wrap it in square brackets.  (Square brackets are also useful when the name of something includes whitespace.)  This may differ for different databases, of course.  I'm thinking in terms of MS SQL.

Comment: the table name is not table. they have their own names. i tried the [] but the invalid syntax is still coming out.

Comment: @widget: Did you replace "table" in the query with the actual name of the table?  Same with the column name(s)?  Sorry if that's a dumb question, but it's often tough to tell how much of a beginning someone may be here.  Show your full query, please.

Comment: yes i replaced both. the full query is: UPDATE tide_data SET value_realnum ='five'

Comment: @widget: If the table `tide_data` exists and has a column named `value_realnum` which is some kind of character data type then there's nothing wrong with that syntax.  At least, not in MS SQL.

Comment: @David: what if the column i want to update is of Boolean data type? Although no matter what kind of column I am putting in here, it's always giving me the error.

Comment: @widget: Again, this depends heavily on the database you're using.  In MS SQL Server a boolean column can be set to `0` or `1`.

Comment: @David: ok i changed it to 0. as i said, the invalid syntax is haunting me. keeps on the table word as well

Comment: @widget: It sounds like the table doesn't exist, then.  Are you sure you're running this query on the correct database?  Also, I'm unfamiliar with the code sample you gave above.  What language/environment is this?  I'm unfamiliar with the `.cursor()` call.

Comment: @David:The table should exist. I succeed in pulling out info of the table. Now just trying to update records instead. The database is postgreSQL and the language is python.